# voice navigator with google map in android

Tags: android, voice, navigator

I have an application for blind people in my country. I want to use map view (Google map) in my application & navigator. Here the navigator tells them where they walk. It means on road there if left  or right turn is there, so navigator can tell us there is left or right turn.. If any one have any link /tutorial source code so plz help me.

Comment: looking for the same thing but this [link](https://support.mapmyfitness.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200075164-Turn-by-turn-voice-directions) say it violates the Google privacy policy, i am not sure and not saying it cannot be done looking for the answer too.